# How do I stop a form from exceeding the window height?

Tags: delphi

My form exceeds the window's height (when I use the splitter which changes a panel's height which in turn changes the form's size).

How can I stop it from resizing like that?

Comment: If the form "grows down", play with the minsize, the position and the alignment of the splitter. The VCL can get things wrong and resize a form when resizing and realigning its contained controls and splitters with minsizes are involved. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835617/how-do-i-avoid-this-unwanted-behaviour-with-delphis-tsplitter-and-panels for more information on this.

Comment: You want to "stop it resizing like that"? You want to stop users from exceeding a certain size, or you want to prevent code that you wrote that changes the height from changing that height?  I have never seen a splitter INSIDE a form change the outside form's height. So obviously you're doing something weird already in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're changing the form size yourself, because I can't find a way to make the splitter do that automatically. You can get the Height of the screen using the `Screen` object in the `Forms` unit. You can simply test against `Screen.Height` or, if you want to better support multiple monitors, test against `Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Handle).Height`

Code sample, untested, should get you started:

```
var MaxFormHeight: Integer;
    NewFormHeight: Integer;
    M: TMonitor;
begin
  // Get the monitor that's hosting the form
  M := M := Screen.MonitorFromWindow(Handle);     
  MaxFormHeight := M.WorkAreaRect.Bottom - M.WorkAreaRect.Top - Top; // Take into account actual available monitor space and the Top of the window
  // Do your stuff to calculate NewFormHeight
  if NewFormHeight > MaxFormHeight then
    NewFormHeight := MaxFormHeight;
  Height := NewFormHeight;
end;
```